# Any Desktop Desklet App?

Tags: gui, desktop-environments, settings

I have used Rainmeter on Windows and wanted a similar tool for Ubuntu. I have tried conky but it was a lot harder. Please refer a tool with a good GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Well Conky is really the only (good) way to go.
You can try Conky with a gui if you think it's hard configuring it with the terminal. You can try conky-manager.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install conky-manager
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also try *Screenlets*, even though I would not recommend it, as it is unmaintained, and are not contained in the official repositories. You may take a look by following this [guide](http://www.noobslab.com/2013/09/desktop-screenlets-for-ubuntulinux.html).

The used terminal commands in the guide for future reference:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/screenlets
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install screenlets
```

The last step should be `sudo apt-get install screenlets-pack-all` if you want to install all available widgets.